# Changing input variables by map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have two `char` inputs, alphabetically between `a` and `h`, and I've created a map between these characters and their natural ordinances.

```
  char x1, x2;
  cin >> x1 >> x2;

  map<char, int> cti;
  cti['a'] = 1;
  cti['b'] = 2;
  cti['c'] = 3;
  cti['d'] = 4;
  cti['e'] = 5;
  cti['f'] = 6;
  cti['g'] = 7;
  cti['h'] = 8;

  x1 = cti.find(x1) -> second;
  x2 = cti.find(x2) -> second;

  cout << x1 << x2;
```

I expected, upon the input of `a b`, for `12` to be the output, but there is nothing output. Using other variables than the inputs themselves, the syntax seems not to work either, so I'm assuming that `find` doesn't take variables as its argument, but I'm not completely sure what I've done wrong.

It may also be possible that there is a more efficient method than with a `map` to accomplish what I want to accomplish, in which case I would appreciate that to be commented, even though it's not really the main question.

Answer (score 0):

No it's much simpler than that, change

```
char x1, x2;
```

to

```
int x1, x2;
```

In your code the compiler is interpreting your integer values as characters. Those characters are not visible when you try to print them.